# change server url from localhost

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I installed teamcity 9.1 on mac os. I can access teamcity via `http://localhost:8111/`. I can change port in file `TeamCity/conf/server.xml` by changing `<Connector port="8111" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`.

But how can I change server url e.g. `http://localhost:8111/` to `http://teamcity.test:8111/`

I tried changing in `server.xml` from `<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">`

But after I start teamcity as `./runAll.sh start` it stills can access from `http://localhost:8111/` but not from `http://teamcity.test:8111/`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from Teamcity UI. Go to Administration -> Global Settings and update Server URL property.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make server accessible by some other url/domain name you need to update the DNS entry to make the address resolve to the IP address of the new server and after all cached DNS results expire, all clients will be automatically using the new server. Also please note that after changing the URL you'll need to:

1. Switch agents to new URL (requires updating serverUrl property in [buildAgent.properties](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Agent+Configuration) on each agent).

   2. Upon new server startup do not forget to update [Server URL](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Server+URL) on Server configuration administration page.