# Teamcity change my domain from localhost to some other name

Tags: dns, certificate, ssl-certificate, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

My question is very simple, I have a Teamcity server, sitting in a Mac computer. All I want to do is change my domain from https://localhost to some other name

How do I do it?

Comment: do you access it from browser ? If yes you may be explicity add this certificate to the truststore so the browser can trust the server.

Comment: hey, I was able to make the access through HTTPS, but now I want to change to domain name how do I do it?
this related post contains exactly my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634554/change-server-url-from-localhost

Comment: okay then you'll have to create a new certificate for the domain and install it in your trust store.

Comment: but how do I change my domain name from localhost to something else?

Comment: nope you cannot. each domain name has its own certificate.you'll need a new certificate with the domain name.

Comment: and where do I get a certificate from the domain? from the same CA as for HTTPS?

Comment: yes if that is your CA

Answer (score -1):

Step-by-Step guide on Teamcity setup

https://blogs.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/